# PHP function with variable as default value for a parameter

Tags: php, function, variables, parameters

By default a PHP function uses `$_GET` variables. Sometimes this function should be called in an situation where `$_GET` is not set. In this case I will define the needed variables as parameter like: `actionOne(234)`

To get an abstract code I tried something like this:

```
function actionOne($id=$_GET["ID"])
```

which results in an *error*:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Is it impossible to define an default parameter by using an variable?

**Edit**

The `actionOne` is called "directly" from an URL using the framework *Yii*. By handling the `$_GET` variables outside this function, I had to do this on an central component (even it is a simple, insignificant function) or I have to change the framework, what I don't like to do.

An other way to do this could be an dummy function (something like an pre-function), which is called by the URL. This "dummy" function handles the variable-issue and calls the `actionOne($id)`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No, this isn't possible, as stated on the [Function arguments manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> The default value must be a constant
>   expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function
>   call.

Instead you could either simply pass in null as the default and update this within your function...

```
function actionOne($id=null) {
    $id = isset($id) ? $id : $_GET['ID'];
    ....
}
```

...or (better still), simply provide $_GET['ID'] as the argument value when you don't have a specific ID to pass in. (i.e.: Handle this outside the function.)

Comment: Same here, the solution breaks encapsulation, the check should happen outside the function.

Comment: I updated my post. In my specific case, your solution looks like the best way... (I will check this out soon) In general I probably would use the solution form @Galen. What do you mean with "simply provide $_GET['ID'] as the argument value"? Is this according to your example?

Comment: isn't it better to use "$id===null?$id=$_GET["ID"]:null;" instead of $id = isset($id) ? $id : $_GET['ID'];?
Because you avoid one assignment of $id, if $id is still set ($id=$id)!?!  ..or is there no different?

Comment: @The Bndr I meant that you'd assign $id before you call the function, rather than in the function itself. In terms of your second point - if you're worried about the overhead of a variable assignment, I suspect you shouldn't be using PHP. :-)

Comment: @middaparka maybe! ;-) but my version of assigning $id is also usable?! Or is your version the "better practice"?

Comment: @The Bndr I think mine is probably closer to the tradition "form" that a ternary operator generally takes (as the assignment is explicit), but yours will work fine. It's just a matter of which you think is more readable/easy to comprehend to be honest.

Answer (score 4):

```
function actionOne( $id=null ) {
    if ($id === null) $id = $_GET['ID'];
}
```

But, i would probably do this outside of the function:

```
// This line would change, its just a for instance
$id = $id ? $id : $_GET['id'];
actionOne( $id );
```

Comment: hi thank you.... there is no other way? ...without handling this problem inside or outside this function?

Comment: I still think you should provide the good practice as the main example and the worse practice as the alternative!

Answer (score 3):

You should get that id before you call the function. Checking for the existence of the parameter breaks encapsulation. You should do something like that:

```
if (isset($_GET["ID"])
{
    $id = $_GET["ID"];
}
else
{
    //$id = something else
}

function doSomethingWithID($id)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use constant variable

```
define('ID',$_GET["ID"]);
function($id = _ID_){
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is impossible.

The default has to be a static variable:

```
function actionOne( $id='something') {
    //code
}
```

Comment: a static variable? and you're passing a string? how does that solve the problem?

Comment: The only thing which is called a dynamic variable in PHP afaik is a variable-variable and that wouldn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Your solution is wrong, you're passing a string as default value, how does that address the original question?

Answer (score 1):

Easy peanuts! 
(Might contain minor mistakes, errors or typos!)

You need a helper function, which will call you main function recursively, but having NULL as default:

Wrong: `function actionOne($id=$_GET["ID"])`

Right:

```
function actionOne($id) {...}
function actionOnewithID($id=NULL) {
  if (NULL==$id){actionOne($_GET["ID"]);}
  else {actionOne($id);
}
```

And if you need to return a value:

```
function actionOne($id) {...}
function actionOnewithID($id=NULL) {
  if (NULL==$id){return(actionOne($_GET["ID"]));}
  else {return(actionOne($id));
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

shortest way is:

```
function actionOne($id = null)
{
     $id = $id ?? $_GET["ID"];
     ...
}
```