# How to set a PHP function's param to a variable as the default value

Tags: php, function, variables

So I'd like to be able to switch a certain function on or off depending on if a variable is true or false. The function would still execute, but because the variable is false, it won't do it's routine.

Something like this

```
$testTF = "T";

function Test($test=$testTF){
echo $test;
}

Test("Go");
```

Of course this won't work, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make it work like intended. This function is sprinkled everywhere in the script, and needs to be in certain places, so I can't just group them all together under one if statement because it would break them.

I know you could just pass the value as a flag every time you call it, but I'm looking for a way to make it assume that value as default unless told otherwise. Maybe I'm looking at globals here but that's dangerous I'm told.

Thanks

Comment: @Dagon: Lol... (you weren't serious, right?)

Comment: Im not PHP developer but for logical comparison isn't $test=$testTF should be $test==$testTF

Comment: The = in the params tells it to set it to some default value if not specified

Comment: @xbonez sets default value, which is what I read that he wanted.

Comment: @Dagon: So, if the default value changes, you expect him to go and change the values every place he is using it? It goes against the principle of DRY and it error-prone. Further, he could be pulling the value from a DB or getting it via user input

Comment: I'm not going to be using a DB with this, it's just a function that would echo something if the variable telling it to go (defined outside the function) said true

Comment: could be this could be that, its only a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do this?

```
$testTF = "T";

function Test($test=NULL){
    if ($test ===NULL) {
        global $testTF;
        $test = $testTF;
    }
    echo $test;
}

Test("Go");
```

Optionally, if you're against using globals, you can encapsulate the default value in a function, like this:

```
function Test($test=NULL){
    if ($test ===NULL) {        
        $test = getDefault();
    }
    echo $test;
}

Test("Go");

function getDefault(){
    //pull default value from wherever
    $testDefault = 'T';
    return $testDefault;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks but the problem there is it can't see the testTF var from in the function. It doesn't crash though :)

Comment: @user1159454: You should definitely be able to see $testF in the function. Have you defined it in the same file, or do you mean you want to access the variable through various files?

Comment: Yes it's all the same file. In PHP I know you can't see variables that aren't either set inside it, or passed as a parameter. I know in javascript that would work

Comment: @user1159454: You have to declare `$testTF` as global first: `global $testTF;` or use `$GLOBALS['testTF']`.

Comment: @user1159454: Oh, I get you now. See edit.

Comment: Awesome, this works. Can you explain exactly why I should fear the GLOBAL variable menace? I understand too much of them messes up things because theyre hard to keep track of and you might accidentally overwrite them, but what else is bad about them?

Comment: I, personally, avoid globals because you don't have much control over them. You could easily declare a new variable with the same name in a function, then later realize you need to use the global variable as well. Further, it is possible that you (or another developer) invariably changes the global variable's value. Encapsulating it in a function allows you to keep it read-only.

Comment: Alright thank you for both methods!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is the way you want to do it is impossible but this is also a duplicate of :
[PHP function with variable as default value for a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859376/php-function-with-variable-as-default-value-for-an-parameter)

Has the answer you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with closures:

```
$testTF = 'T';

$Test = function ($test = null) use ($testTF){
    if ($test === null) $test = $testTF;
    echo $test;
};

$Test(); //T
$Test(null); //T
$Test('Go'); //Go
```