# How do you reference another parameter as the default value of a parameter in a function?

Tags: php, default-value, function-definition

Below, I have a function call that gives one of the list items the `active` class (from Bootstrap) if the current filename matches the first argument of the `giveClassActive()`. Each list item has text it will show, an href for the page to direct to, and a filename that it is checking for. Only sometimes are the `$href` and `$file` values different because `#` must become `%23`. So, I want to give the `$href` a default value of `$file`.

```
<?php
function giveClassActive($file, $href, $show) {
    echo '<li class = "';
    $filename = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $file_name = end($filename);
    if ($file_name == $file) {
        echo 'active';
    }
    echo '">';
    echo '<a href = "' . $href . '">' . $show . '</a></li>';
}
giveClassActive('calculator #5.php', 'calculator %235.php', 'Calculator');
giveClassActive('contact.php', 'contact.php', 'Contact'); 
?>
```

My question is: How do I reference another parameter in a function definition?

I have tried

`function giveClassActive($file, $href = $file, $show) {`

and

`function giveClassActive($file, $href = this.$file, $show) {`

which produce

`Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.22-1\apache2\htdocs\LarryUllman\Chapter 3\includes\header.html on line 20`

Note: The output is

[image: Output]

**Edit after put on hold**

My question is different from [PHP function with variable as default value for a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859376/php-function-with-variable-as-default-value-for-a-parameter) because that question does not ask about referencing a parameter, but rather another variable.

Comment: note about dupes: It's not necessarily the **same question** - but the same **solution** that makes it a dupe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best is

```
if ($href == null)
    $href = $file;
```